# How to create an animated gif image from a number of png images?

Tags: bash, image-processing, imagemagick, gif, animated-gif

I have an image file "image.png" that I wanted to create a .gif image of out of it.
I wrote a small script to get 100 images of different sizes (1% - 100%) of the that image, then I removed the original image (image.png) from the containing folder, and used this command to generate the gif image I wanted:

```
convert -delay 10 -loop 0 *.png image.gif
```

When I checked the gif image, I could see the largest image (100% size) as a still picture (to my eyes) and the smaller images started to show up at the upper left corner of the image, from 1% - 100%, with the 100% image coinciding with the original picture that's always shown up.
I expected to see the image grow up in size from the center of the rectangular/square are in the image software (gthumb) I use, which is not what I get?

I checked the smaller images, and they are fine, and I also ran a slide show of the images with a high speed and showed me what I expected to have in my gif file. I use Linux.

Update 1:
Here is the script I used to generate the 100 images, before 'Mark Setchell' reply:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..100};
do
if [ $i -lt 10 ]; then
convert -resize $i% lena.png 00$i.png
elif [ $i -lt 100 ]; then
convert -resize $i% lena.png 0$i.png
else
convert -resize $i% lena.png $i.png
fi
done
```

which produced the 100 images.
Then as per 'Mark Setchell' reply, I used this code:

```
for ((i=0;i<100;i++)) ; do
   convert checked-box.png -resize $i% -background none -gravity center -extent 512x512 miff:-
done | convert miff:- -delay 80 anim.gif
```

[here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IxvqGR9QXoYlG5jQry9whlyE-c4mQd81) is the result I got.
And this is [lena.png](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1PH9H7lNB3Zf5i_MikCVoyi-T0G-DnFNI) that I used.

Update 2:

I edited the following command to change the input file name.

```
for ((i=0;i<100;i++)) ; do
       convert lena.png -resize $i% -background none -gravity center -extent 512x512 miff:-
    done | convert miff:- -delay 80 anim.gif
```

Comment: Try changing your script that generates the 100 pictures to `convert input.png ...as before... +repage -gravity center -background none -extent WIDTHxHEIGHT frame-00N.png` where WIDTH and HEIGHT are the size of the final a GIF image.

Comment: `convert checked-box.png +repage -gravity center -background none -extent 256x256 frame-100.png` generated a single png file (frame-100.png)

Comment: Please edit your question and show how you generated your 100 images.

Comment: I used the following script that I wrote:
`#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..100};
do
    if [ $i -lt 10 ]; then
 convert -resize $i% checked-box.png 00$i.png
    elif [ $i -lt 100 ]; then
 convert -resize $i% checked-box.png 0$i.png
    else
 convert -resize $i% checked-box.png $i.png
    fi
done`

Comment: I don't understand why you produced 100 images again when my command generates them already itself? I also don't understand why you use an image called `checked_box` as input when you said you used `lena`?

Comment: I did not. I just wrote what I did before your command, for the sake of giving a clearer picture.
I used your command in a directory that only included lena.png and t the above gif file is the result.
checked-box.png is a type (original file name.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you want something like the following. I avoid writing all 100 intermediate files to disk, and instead write them in a streaming format (**MIFF** or **Magick Image File Format**) to a final `convert` that gathers them all up and animates them. Another *"trick"* is to centre each image on a transparent background (`-background none`) so that all the frames of the GIF are the same size.

```
for ((i=0;i<100;i++)) ; do
   convert lena.png -resize $i% -background none -gravity center -extent 512x512 miff:-
done | convert miff:- -delay 80 anim.gif
```

[image]

---

Note that the `-extent` parameter determines the dimensions of the final image. If you make the extent smaller than your original image you will get a zoom beyond 1:1 full-size. I guess you *probably* want the extent set to exactly match your input image, then the last frame of the animation will be your full, uncropped, original image. But you have the code now, so experiment!

Note that you can run the animation backwards and create a shrinking effect, instead of zooming by either running the loop backwards from 100 down to 1 or by adding `-reverse` before `-delay` to reverse the order of the frames.

---

**Keywords**: ImageMagick, image, image processing, zoom, shrink, GIF, animated GIF, command-line

Comment: Note that the animation included in the answer is not the actual animation produced by the command because that exceeds the 2MB limit on StackOverflow, so I made a smaller one that is less smooth because it has fewer frames.

Comment: It worked in the sense that the image starts from the center. But I still get the original image as a background, that is, the images starts from small to big while the original image is the background. I checked with 'lena.png' to make sure there is nothing wrong with my  image, but still the same.
I use Linux Mint and tried both Xviewer version 1.8.1, and gthumb.

Comment: Please click `edit` under your original question and add the exact image and code you used and if at all possible provide a link to your result - via Dropbox or Google Drive or somesuch. Thank you.

Comment: I believe I could solve the background problem.
I used this command (practically the same as yours, without `-background none` parameter:
`for ((i=0;i<100;i++)) ; do    convert lena.png -resize $i% -gravity center -extent 512x512 miff:-; done | convert miff:- -delay 80 anim.gif` Now I can get your gif image.